# C# Selenium - Is there any way to check if the Element Exists or not without throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, selenium, nosuchelementexception

Is there any way to check if the element exists on the page without throwing an exception using selenium C#.

Answer (score 10):

Your alternative might be to use `.FindElements`. Given a selector that doesn't match anything it'll return an empty list as opposed to throw an exception.

```
var elementExists = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("something")).Any();
```

`Any` is a LINQ method that merely checks if the list contains *something* (think `.Count == 0`).

Answer (score 1):

I would use try catch block with `explicit` wait

```
public bool CheckElementExist(string state)
{
    //Write the selector carefully.
    By byCss = By.CssSelector("#view-" + state + "");
    try
    {
     //Explicit wait to check if element exist for 10s   
     new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byCss));
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still throws an element not found exception

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

There is something called an explicit and implicit wait take a look at the above link.